# oembed_result not running on my Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I implemented the following Wordpress filter in function.php file of my Wordpress theme:

```
function change_oembed($html, $url, $args){

   $video_pattern = "#(\W|^)(youtube)(\W|$)#";
   $notification = '<div class="cookieconsent-optout-marketing">Please 
                    <a href="javascript:Cookiebot.renew()">accept marketing-cookies</a> 
                   to watch this video.
                   </div>';


   if(preg_match($video_pattern, $url)){                

    $matches = null;
    preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $url, $matches);

    $gdpr_youtube = '<iframe data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' .
                     $matches[1] . '" data-cookieconsent="marketing" frameborder="0"
                     allowfullscreen></iframe>';


    $new_html = '<div class="clearfix"></div>' . $notification . $gdpr_youtube;
 } else {
    $new_html = $html;

}

return $new_html;
}

 add_filter( 'oembed_result', array($this, 'change_oembed'), 999, 3 );
```

I can see the result of this filter in the post. I only see the youtube.com video URL text. I tried clearing the cache withint wordpress and the browser (using FastCache plugin), I've tried putting the code outside the if-else statement but nothing works.

**update:** I also tried `video_embed_html` instead of `oembed_result` but it still doesn't work.

**Update 2:** The function is not being called. I just put some question marks just to see if I see them in code, but I don't. So the `change_oembed` function isn't called at all.

I checked that the regex works, and it does works for that YouTube URL, so it's not the regex issue.

Comment: What is $this in your code? Is it any declared class variable or what? Your code shows the function is independent and doesn't belong to any class, but your filter tries to run class method, not function. So may be you need to use  add_filter( 'oembed_result','change_oembed', 999, 3 );
insteaad